# Is MVP a design pattern or an architectural pattern ? What about MvC and MvvM?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, mvvm, mvp

After doing some research on android patterns I kept finding different answers. Some people will start talking about design pattern, architectural or even architectural presentation patterns.

I'm reaching the conclusion that they are all architectural presentation pattern but MvC is an architectural pattern while MvP & MvvM are design pattern on the same rank as something like the design pattern observer. Is it correct?

Answer (score 5):

*Design pattern* is a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem within a given context. They reside in the domain of modules and interconnections. They are very connected to your code.

On the other hand *Architectural patterns* are similar to software design patterns but have a **broader scope**. They are usually describing an overall pattern followed by an entire system.

For me Mvc, Mvp and Mvvm are all architectural patterns

Other architectural patterns you may hear off are (the list is not exhaustive) :

- Event Driven architecture
- CQRS
- REST
- Microservices
- SOA
- Pipe & Filter architecture

you can find some examples on wiki : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_architecture_styles_and_patterns

Comment: I think that MVC, MVP and MVVM are architectural patterns and doesn't depend on the context. Design patterns are medium-scale tactics that flesh out some of the structure and behavior of entities and their relationships in your code. Like I said architectural patterns are high-level strategies that concerns large-scale components, the global properties and mechanisms of a system. MVC is one of the "architectural" pattern to deal with separation of concerns. The same goes for MVP and MVVM